# Parsley example from site does not work?

Tags: jquery, html, validation, parsley.js, customvalidator

I use the [Parsley](http://parsleyjs.org) example from [the documetation page site](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/customvalidator.html?question1=yes&languages=c&question2=yes&why=):

I save a page on my hard drive with the folowing content:

```
<form id="demo-form" data-parsley-validate>
  <label for="question">Do you code? *</label>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" name="question1" value="true" required /> Yes
    <input type="radio" name="question1" value="false" /> No
  </p>

  <label for="languages">If yes, in which language(s)?</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="languages" data-parsley-conditionalrequired='["[name=\"question1\"]:checked", "yes"]' data-parsley-validate-if-empty data-parsley-success-class="" data-parsley-conditionalrequired-message="This value is required since you are a programmer!" />

  <label for="question">Do you eat dog food? *</label>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" name="question2" value="yes" required /> Yes
    <input type="radio" name="question2" value="no" /> No
  </p>

  <label for="why">If no, why?</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="why" data-parsley-conditionalrequired='["[name=\"question2\"]:checked", "no"]' data-parsley-validate-if-empty data-parsley-success-class="" data-parsley-conditionalrequired-message="This value is required since you do not eat dog food!" />

  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  window.ParsleyConfig = {
    validators: {
      conditionalrequired: {
        fn: function (value, requirements) {
          // if requirements[0] value does not meet requirements[1] expectation, field is required
          if (requirements[1] == $(requirements[0]).val() && '' == value)
          return false;

          return true;
        },
        priority: 32
      }
    }
  };
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://parsleyjs.org/dist/parsley.js"></script>
```

But any custom vaidators does not seems to work.

I mean, the logic of the custom validator si not respected. "If yes, in which language(s)?" I select Yes, and don't fill the language...

Where is the problem?

A fiddle is available also **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/1ykk4q0x/30/)**

Comment: Any errors at all? Broken paths? JS errors?

Comment: No errors, but the logic is not respected. see my edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
'["[name=\"question1\"]:checked", "yes"]'
```

in

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="languages" data-parsley-conditionalrequired='["[name=\"question1\"]:checked", "yes"]' data-parsley-validate-if-empty data-parsley-success-class="" data-parsley-conditionalrequired-message="This value is required since you are a programmer!" />
```

to

```
'["[name=\"question1\"]:checked", "true"]'
```

You've got to use the `value` rather than the text in

```
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="true" required /> Yes
```

---

**EDIT**

Per comments, an alternative (and more consistent) solution is to change the HTML input `value`s:

```
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="yes" required /> Yes
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="no" /> No
```

Comment: yah, just found it myself, so we were in parallel...! The second condition works, because the right condition is set "Yes/No" as values!

Comment: added a issue: https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/issues/886, I propose replacing value="yes" rather than "value='true'" ;)

Comment: `value='yes'` would actually be better since it would be consistent with the second example.

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune oh... if there where also an example of validating Google's reCaptcha, wil be really great! kill some days on it! (